# How do I calculate TAS from IAS in this question?

Tags: airspeed

How can I calculate the answer to this EASA PPL ECQB question?

> An aircraft cruises at altitude 5000 ft on a heading of 180° with an
>   indicated airspeed of 100 kt. The wind vector is 180° with 30 kt.
>   Neglecting instrument and position errors, which will be the
>   approximate true airspeed (TAS)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! That sounds like a homework question, and you should at least show what you have done to try to solve it yourself.

Comment: You don’t have enough information. You also need OAT (outside air temperature).

Answer (score 4):

Just convert 100 kt indicated to TAS at 5000 ft using your flight computer.  The wind data is a smoke screen to throw you astray if you don't really understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Understood. Thank you alot.